# pass keyname in array_filter

Tags: php, array-filter

`array_filter` only passes array values, not keynames... how to access keyname?
for example:

```
$array= array('country'=>'Spain');
array_filter($array,'my_func');
```

with **`my_func`** i want to check:

 `if KEYNAME == 'country' then` ...

Comment: @Patrick-Q and @ Rizier123 
Read the question before marking them as DUPLICATE!

In that topic there is no answer for my question!

Comment: Actually, the accepted answer in the linked question is the same solution as what you have accepted here, but actually with a _more precise_ flag passed.  So maybe actually read and understand the answers before flying off the handle.

Comment: @PatrickQ thanks. youa re partially right. i didnt fly of my handle, no worry.  just that answer was a bit difficult for me to understand directly. however, before closing the topic, please understand, that if i could get in that answer, i wouldnt had asked here. so, if user asks question, then help him if you can. if not, then at least give hint. look at the accepted answer, that was what i was searching for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

array_filter can pass them.

`array_filter($array, 'my_func', ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);`

and `my_func` will then be passed two params; the key, and the value.

[array_filter doc page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)